# Execute cron job automatically after a specific interval of time in windows

Tags: hooks, cron

I've created a custom module in drupal and implemented `hook_cron`. My hook is working perfectly, when I click on run cron button from admin interface.

How can I automatically execute my hook after a specific time interval is passed,  without clicking on the *Run cron* button from the administrative interface?

Answer (score 1):

Drupal supports two types of cron jobs:

### Poormanscron

This is the default Drupal 7 cron, where at the end of a page request after a certain amount of time, hook_cron is called. This is controlled by the `Run cron every ...` setting at `admin/config/system/cron`.

This means that if cron is configured to run every 3 hours, the first user to visit the page after 3 hours will trigger cron. This also means on a low-traffic site that it can many more hours before cron is actually called.

### Scheduled cron

This is a much more reliable method which does not involve the user. The principle is that the cron page is called from an external source (usually crontab on the server) at a set interval. As long as the server is up, it will run guaranteed every 3 hours.

In order to enable this, make sure to disable Poormanscron at `admin/config/system/cron` (set it to run never). And create a cron job ([General and Linux manual](https://www.drupal.org/node/23714)).

In case of a Windows environemt, one can use Windows' built in scheduled tasks. Please refer to [this manual page](https://www.drupal.org/node/31506).

UPDATE
Be aware that the manual is a little outdated, since Drupal 7 the cron script is protected by a token (to prevent DDoS). So where you see to call `http://www.example.com/cron.php`, add your site specific token. This can be found on your site's status page and looks like this: `http://www.example.com/cron.php?cron_key=xxxxxxxxxx`.

Answer (score 0):

Create a Drupal 7 Module. Then add this following function.

```
function my_sample_module_cron() {
    $sample_module_rule =  60 * 60; //Second * Minute [You can d0 60 * 60 * 2 for running cron in every two hours
    $date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", time());
    if ((time() - variable_get('sample_module_rule ', 0)) > $sample_module_rule ) { 
        variable_set('sample_module_rule ', time());
        sample_function();
    }
}
```

Now visit **admin/config/system/cron** in Administrator Login.

[image]

From **Run cron every** option select the time gap for each cron run. In there you will find option from "One Hour" to "1 Week".

If you need smaller timegap install **Ultimate Cron** Module - https://www.drupal.org/project/ultimate_cron . 
Where you will be able to setup Advance Cron settings.